# Cant set Array in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

```
var arr = defaults.arrayForKey("kWeeks") as [WeekReport]?
if arr? {
    var arr2 = arr!
    arr2.append(report)
    defaults.setObject(arr2, forKey: "kWeeks")           // Crash
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

I try to set `arr2` which will be the add after optional checking. But it crashes on `setObject()` with error: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Ive checked, with `println()` and `arr2` is not nil and contains the element which is appended in the sample above. And `report` is of type `WeekReport`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = defaults.arrayForKey("kWeeks") as [WeekReport]?
```

Is doing a forced casting to an optional array of `WeekReport`. Instead, you really want to do an optional casting:

```
if let arr = defaults.arrayForKey("kWeeks") as? [WeekReport] {
    arr.append(report)
    defaults.setObject(arr, forKey: "kWeeks")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

This says, "if there is an array for "kWeeks" that can be cast to an array of `WeekReport`, do the following with it as `arr`"

You also need to make sure that `WeekReport` inherits from the [NSCoding protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) so that it can be converted to data.

Comment: Hmm im still getting the error though and the ass should be a var here.

Comment: @Arbitur, does WeekReport inherit from NSObject and implement the NSCoding protocol?

Comment: yeah I just thought of that why it is crashing and it does have the NSCoding protocol I just have to Archive it...

Comment: @Arbitur what is the call stack when the crash occurs?